# HTML javascript how to chnage target value for href

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the target of

```
 <a ng-hide="cart.getTotalCount() < 1" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="./Checkout">
```

My intention is to pass one parameter to Checkout method depending on circumstance. I want to achieve this in HTML/Javascript

Comment: Is Checkout supposed to be a js function?  If so, you'll want that as your onclick.  In that function you can filter on whatever conditionals you want.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question you can do :

`<a ng-hide="cart.getTotalCount() < 1" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-href="{{computeCheckoutUrl()}}">`

And you can have in your controller something like

```
$scope.computeCheckoutUrl = function() {
   if (test)
     return './Checkout?var=2';
   return './Checkout';
};
```

But I recommend you to take a look at built-in tools like [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) to do things like that.

Comment: Hi can we not do it within the page using javascript, I need to check the current page's URL to build the logic

Comment: Well... this is within the page using javascript, what is the problem ?